# Why should I use 'rdtsc' differently on x86 and x86_x64?

Tags: c, cpu-registers, rdtsc

I know that `rdtsc` loads the current value of the processor's time-stamp counter into the two registers: EDX and EAX. In order to get it on x86 I need to do it like that (assuming using Linux):

```
    unsigned long lo, hi;
    asm( "rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));
    return lo;
```

and for x86_x64:

```
        unsigned long lo, hi;
        asm( "rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi) ); 
        return( lo | (hi << 32) );
```

why is that? Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: Those definitions are missing `volatile` on the asm; they're not safe for timing if the compiler can see the start and end.  I wonder if that's intentional in Linux because they're never using it for microbenchmarking inside the kernel?  But IDK where in Linux it could usefully CSE.

Comment: TL:DR: **you shouldn't use it differently**.  See [Get CPU cycle count?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567) for asm that works on both 32 and 64-bit.  (And my answer which shows how to use the `__rdtsc()` intrinsic instead).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RDTSC always writes its 64-bit result split into hi/lo halves in EDX and EAX, even in 64-bit mode ([see the manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtsc)), unfortunately not packing the 64-bit TSC into just RAX.  That's why extra work is needed after the asm statement.

To make a single 64-bit integer from it, you need to shift `hi` to the place it belongs as part of an `unsigned long`.  `lo` is already in the right place, and writing those 32-bit register zeroed the upper bits of both registers, so we can just OR the (shifted) halves together without having to AND the low half.

In x86-64 Linux, `unsigned long` is a 64-bit type so the kernel actually uses both halves of the RDTSC return value.

**The only reason the 32-bit version is simpler is that the kernel is truncating the result to 32-bit by throwing away the high half**.  If you do want a 64-bit TSC in 32-bit mode, the same C source works there, too (with `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long`),  although it wouldn't compile to shift and OR instructions.  The compiler would just know that it has a 64-bit integer whose halves are in EDX and EAX.

See also [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567) - and for real use, don't forget to make these `asm volatile`.  Otherwise the compiler can assume that repeated executions of this produce the same output, e.g. `end-start` = 0 after optimization.

Comment: So am I absolutely right, that `rdtsc` loads the current value of the processor's time-stamp counter into the two registers: EDX and EAX, not into registers from EAX to EDX? (EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX)

Comment: rdtsc always return 64 bit value so for 32 bit machine it stores into EDX and EAX  and yes you are right.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is not in `rdtsc`, but in what the Linux kernel wants to do with it.

In 32bit, it returns a 32bit value. So the value in eax is good enough.
In 64bit, it returns a 64bit value. So it needs to combine the values from both registers.

Comment: According to the [gcc doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html), even in 32bit OSes, 64bit value is returned for `__asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc":"=A"(tick))`. Search for `rdtsc`in the referenced link.

Comment: @wlnirvana, this would be a good way to get a 64bit timestamp on 32bit. But Linux chose to use `long`, so only 32 bits are needed.

Comment: @ugoren could you please elaborate on "Linux chose to use `long`"?

Comment: @wlnirvana, the function returns `long`,  which is 32bit on a 32bit system. This is how the developers chose to define it.

Comment: You mean the function the OP used which returns `lo`? Yes that is of course 32bit. But if the style in the gcc doc is used, I think 64bit value would be returned?

Comment: @wlnirvana:  `return( lo | ((uint64_t)hi << 32) )` works in both modes.  No reason to mess around with `"=A"`.  See Mysticial's answer on [Get CPU cycle count?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567).